# Prove or disprove: There exists a set of two elements which generates the group $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove or disprove: There exists a set of two elements which generates the group $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

I think the statement is NOT true. If we treat $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as a vector space, then its dimension is 3. Therefore, we need at least three basis vectors in order to generate the whole space. Is this right, please?

Comment: prove that you cannot generate (1,0,0) (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) then

Comment: I disapprove.  Disprove!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuitive argument can be turned into a (dis)proof:

Assume that ${\mathbb Z}^3\subset{\mathbb Q}^3$ is generated by two integer triples $a$, $b$. In particular the vectors $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$, $e_3=(0,0,1)$ would then be integer linear combinations of $a$ and $b$. It follows that an arbitrary vector $x\in{\mathbb Q}^3$ would be a rational linear combination of $a$, $b\in{\mathbb Q}^3$. This is clearly not the case, since ${\mathbb Q}^3$ is a three-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I approve this argument.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "no". Suppose you can generate $\mathbb{Z}^3$ by two elements $a,b$. Take the quotient $\mathbb{Z}^3/p\mathbb{Z}^3\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^3$ for some prime $p$. This is $3$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Since $a,b$ generated $\mathbb{Z}^3$, their images $a',b'$ must generate the quotient $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^3$. But this is $3$-dimensional vector space. Contradiction.

Comment: Commutative rings, such as the integers, also have the so-called "invariant dimension property" which means that doing this sort of argument to pass to a field is not necessary, depending on what the OP already knows.

Comment: This is true. But the fact about vector spaces is very basic, and usualy one learnes it before learning the general property of rings you've mentioned.

Comment: @Jeff All proofs I know of this “invariant dimension property” basically use reduction modulo a maximal ideal (or passing to the ring of quotients for domains).